# It is possible to pass the value to profile attributes using ssjs script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

It is possible to pass the value to profile attributes using ssjs script this is my code

```
<script runat=server>
 Platform.Load("Core","1");
 var ts =Send.Definition.Init('Error_Email_for_Sage');
  var status = ts.Send({Firstname:"ravi"});
Write(status);
if(status != "OK")
{
  Write("Error");
}
else
 {
Write("OK");
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: If you are looking to send to a single recipient, the TriggeredSend object should be used, not the Send.Definition.  Send.Definition is used for sending to an entire list of recipients which would likely contain multiple recipients.

Comment: @mac i need to pass the value for profile attributes  through Send.Definition.Init not TriggeredSend object

Comment: The system doesn't support the ability to define subscriber profile attributes on the send definition. Profile attributes would need to be set on the subscriber.